# warnings in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode

i'm getting this two messages:

warning: 'MainView' may not respond to '-switchToNoGridView'
Messages without a matching method signature will be assumed to return 'id' and accept '...' as arguments

1st here:

```
//GridView.m
#import "GridView.h"
#import "MainView.h"

@implementation GridView

-(IBAction)switchToNoGridView {
    [mainView switchToNoGridView];
}

@end
```

2nd here:

warning: 'MainView' may not respond to '-goBack'
Messages without a matching method signature will be assumed to return 'id' and accept '...' as arguments

in this:

```
//NoGridView.m
#import "NoGridView.h"
#import "MainView.h"

@implementation NoGridView

-(IBAction)goBack {
    [mainView goBack];
}

@end
```

how to avoid these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared `switchToNoGridView` and `goBack` in the class interface for `MainView`?

This warning means that the method signatures could  not be found in the class of the instance that you are calling the method on; since message dispatch in Objective-C is done at runtime this is allowed, however a warning is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure from your code, but I think you're encountering one of two errors. Either:

**You haven't declared the methods** `switchToNoGridView` or `goBack` in the MainView class declaration. For Xcode to know that an object responds to a method, you have to include its definition in the class header file, like this:

```
@interface MainView : ParentObject {
    // instance variables
}
// properties
 - (void)switchToNoGridView;
 - (void)goBack;
@end
```

This assumes you actually want to declare them as `(void)`, of course - they can have return values, but since you don't do anything with the result of the call in your code, I'm assuming they're void. Or:

**You meant to call MainView the class, not `mainView` the object.** Since we can't see your property or instance variable definitions for GridView.h, nor can we see the current method declarations in MainView.h, it's possible that you have a static method `+(void)switchToNoGridView` and `+(void)goBack` declared on MainView, but you're calling it on an instance `mainView` of MainView. For example:

```
@interface AClass : NSObject { }
+ (void)doSomething;
@end

@implementation AClass
+ (void)doSomething {
    NSLog(@"Doing something");
}
@end
```

```
#import "AClass.h"
@interface AnotherClass : NSObject {
    AClass *aClass;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) AClass *aClass;
 - (void)doSomethingElse;
@end

@implementation AnotherClass
- (void)doSomethingElse {
    [aClass doSomething]; // This will break at runtime
    [AClass doSomething]; // but this won't
}
@end
```

Basically, it's possible you've confused class methods with object methods. Either way, you should check your MainView header file for the appropriate method definitions.

Comment: this is my MainView:

//MainView
#import "MainView.h"
#import "GridView.h"
#import "NoGridView.h"

@implementation MainView

-(void)awakeFromNib {
 [self addSubview:gridView];
 [self addSubview:infoView];

}

-(void)switchToNoGridView {
 [gridView removeFromSuperview];
 [self addSubview:nogridView];
}

-(void)goBack {
 [nogridView removeFromSuperview];
 [self addSubview:gridView];
}

@end